# cookie value changes, when gets to browser

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I set cookie in php file on server side this way:

```
 <?php
 setcookie("msession","data:name", time()+3600,"/");
 ?>
```

but my browser receives in headers:

```
 Set-Cookie: msession=data%3Aname; expires=Mon, 17-Mar-2014 01:33:32 GMT; path=/
```

I expect to reveive `msession=data:name...`, but there is `%3A` , not `:`.

Thx for help.

```
edit:
```

this javascript code:

```
  function showcookie()
 {
   var value=getCookie("msession");
   alert(value);
 };

 function getCookie(cname)
 {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++)
  {
    var c = ca[i].trim();
    if (c.indexOf(name)==0) 
    { 
     alert(c.substring(name.length,c.length));
     return c.substring(name.length,c.length);

    }
  }
  return "";
 }
```

still gives me `data%3Aname`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct, the `:` is [`rawurlencode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)d as `%3A`. You should get back your cookie data as you expect it. You can verify this by dumping `$_COOKIE`:

```
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

Comment: @TimmWolla I run 'alert(getCookie("msession"));' and still have  '%3A'. Should i do something on server side?

Comment: @maciekm What is `getCookie`? Probably your cookie reading code is unable to properly parse cookies that are valid according to the spec.

Comment: @TimmWolla, i'm sorry, you are right,i added getcookie function.